# Libcrypt.so.1 error after dist-update on Debian

Tags: debian, upgrade

I have the following problem:

I was updating debian on my lenovo laptop from distro 4.19 to latest.

During upgrade the shell give me an error then I can't use sudo or su due authentication error.

So I rebooted and I need to boot in recovery mode.

I tried to do a apt--fix-broken install

But I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF7dv.jpg)

/usr/bin/python3: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot  open shared object file: no such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test$? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)
E: failure running script/usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10

Actually I have a Debian 4.19.152-1 distro x86_64

I can't connect on internet cause dhcp server isn't installed.

Can u help me?

Thanks

I tried to solve using apt --fix-broken   install but it give me the error up above.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue trying to upgrade a machine from Debian 10 (buster) to 12 (bookworm) and found [this thread on the Debian bug tracker](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=993755).

The thread is tagged `wontfix`, but one of the participants posted a workaround which ended up working for me. Reproducing it here, but full credit to the [original author](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=993755#27):

```bash
cd /tmp
apt -y download libcrypt1
dpkg-deb -x libcrypt1_1%3a4.4.25-2_amd64.deb  .
cp -av lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/* /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
apt -y --fix-broken install
```

After running these commands, I was able to retry the `apt upgrade && apt full-upgrade` that had originally failed with your error, and was successful.